# How to merge XML in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

It doesn't seem that any amount of reading the docs will help me.  Consider the simplified example:

```
declare @table1 table ( id int, parent xml )
insert @table1 values( 1, '<Root></Root>' )
declare @table2 table ( id int, guts xml )
insert @table2 values( 1, '<Guts>hi mom!</Guts>' )

select t1.parent.query('')
from @table1 t1 inner join @table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

What would be passed to the query function to generate this result?

```
<Root><Guts>hi mom!</Guts></Root>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is not set based, but maybe it will help (SQL2008 only)

```
declare @table1 table ( id int, parent xml )
insert @table1 values( 1, '<Root></Root>' )
declare @table2 table ( id int, guts xml )
insert @table2 values( 1, '<Guts>hi mom!</Guts>' )

DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @results table (id int, results xml);

DECLARE idCursor CURSOR FOR 
    select id from @table1
OPEN idCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM idCursor INTO @id

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @parent xml, @guts xml

    SELECT @parent = parent FROM @table1 where id = 1;
    SELECT @guts = guts FROM @table2 where id = 1;
    SET @parent.modify('insert sql:variable("@guts") into (/Root[1])');

    INSERT @results (id, results) values (@id, @parent);

    FETCH NEXT FROM idCursor INTO @id

END 

CLOSE idCursor
DEALLOCATE idCursor

select * from @results;
```

Comment: This is fine since I won't need to use cursors.

Comment: Why is SQL 2008 only? Wouldn't work on 2005 also? You need to use @id in the two selects inside the cursor loop btw.

Comment: Remus, you're right of course. Should have used @id.
I said SQL 2008 only because of the issue reported here: http://tinyurl.com/lst3cz

Answer (score 5):

You are asking for an XML operation, not for a relational operation. What you want is to produce a new XML by *inserting* a fragment of XML into it, which means you have to use the [xml.modify()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx) method. Technically this is possible, but the modify() **must** be called within an update context, so it won't work in a SELECT. It can work in a SET or in an UPDATE:

```
UPDATE t1
 SET parent.modify(N'insert sql:column("t2.guts") into (/Root)[1]')
FROM @table1 t1
 JOIN @table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
SELECT * from @table1;
```

If you must have the result in a SELECT then you'll have to shred the XML into relational table, join that and reconstruct the XML back using FOR XML.